# Computing a function over variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, constexpr

I am trying to figure out which is the most idiomatic way implement a function over a variadic type list. For example, computing the maximum size of all the types. I understand there exist several approaches to accomplish such a task, but I would like to know when to choose which strategy.

These are the mechanisms I would consider (there may exist more, please mention if so):

- Type traits (ideally succinctly with using declarations):

  ```
  template <typename Head>
  using max_size = typename std::integral_constant<size_t, sizeof(Head)>::type;

  template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
  using max_size = ?;
  ```
- `constexpr` functions:

  ```
  template <typename Head>
  constexpr size_t max_size() { return sizeof(Head); }

  template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
  constexpr size_t max_size() { ? }
  ```

My question is twofold:

1. What features of the computation determine what strategy to choose?
2. In each case, how would an example implementation for the maximum size example described above look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally prefer functions rather than traits, I find them easier to manipulate and more natural. But that's certainly subjective ;)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Head>
constexpr size_t max_size() { return sizeof(Head); }

template <typename Head, typename Next, typename... Tail>
constexpr size_t max_size() {
    return max_size<Head>() > max_size<Next, Tail...>() ?
           max_size<Head>() : max_size<Next, Tail...>();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "int: " << max_size<int>() << "\n";
  std::cout << "char, short, int: " << max_size<char, short, int>() << "\n";
  std::cout << "char, double, int: " << max_size<char, double, int>() << "\n";
}
```

In action at [liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3af95db1f4235401ea0cf6dc318e75f2):

```
int: 4
char, short, int: 4
char, double, int: 8
```

Comment: This is the shortest and clearest solution of the available answers. Another plus point is that it does not rely on Boost.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin: Yes, I tend to turn to `constexpr` because they are *so* more readable than meta-programming tricks. Less boilerplate, and more habit at reading functions.

Answer (score 3):

I would stay away from strictly using `constexpr` as they are harder to compose. For instance, I'm not even sure high-order metafunctions are possible with `constexpr`, if so they use function pointers as template parameters which is ugly.

In general, I start with a metafunction class:

```
struct max_size {
  template<typename... Ts>
  struct apply : parampack_foldl::apply<boost::mpl::quote2<boost::mpl::max>, typename boost::mpl::sizeof_<Ts>::type...>;
};
```

Then create an alias to lessen typing:

```
template<typename... Ts>
using MaxSize = typename max_size::apply<Ts>::type;
```

Or, create a constexpr function:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr size_t max_size() { return max_size::apply<Ts...>::type::value; }
```

The second step is really just a matter of style, what really matters is that you have the first which gives you the most to work with.

Comment: I like the idea of high-order metafunctions. It would allow to write a single `max` function and pass in another metafunction to compute the size. It actually seems to work fine together with constexpr functions: http://liveworkspace.org/code/5809994d109ad35a1b68d2beb81b3ddd (The link points to Matthieu's example, slightly modified.)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, there is also the technique of inheritance:

```
#include <cstddef>
using std::size_t;

template<size_t ...S> struct max_size_t;

template<size_t S1, size_t S2, size_t ...Rest>
struct max_size_t<S1, S2, Rest...>
   : max_size_t<(S2 < S1) ? S1 : S2, Rest...> {
};

template<size_t S>
struct max_size_t<S> {
  static const int value = S;
}; 

template<> struct max_size_t<> {
  static const int value = 0;
};

template<typename ...T> struct max_size : max_size_t<sizeof(T)...> {};

// Using the same test-harness as Matthieu M:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "int: " << max_size<int>::value << "\n";
  std::cout << "char, short, int: " << max_size<char, short, int>::value << "\n";
  std::cout << "char, double, int: " << max_size<char, double, int>::value << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Also at [liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/7ce51b276deb6263b1af1e95bda7f0ca).

Although this is not a way I'd choose to implement `max_size`, it's very handy when the desired function is one which returns a type (highly contrived example follows):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, bool B=(sizeof(T1)>sizeof(T2))> struct selector;
template<typename T1, typename T2> struct selector<T1, T2, true> { using type = T1; };
template<typename T1, typename T2> struct selector<T1, T2, false> { using type = T2; };

template<typename T1, typename ...Rest> struct largest_type;

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Rest>
struct largest_type<T1, T2, Rest...>
   : largest_type<typename selector<T1, T2>::type, Rest...> {};

template<typename T1> struct largest_type<T1> { using type = T1; };

#include <iostream>
int main() {
  static const unsigned long long u = 1ULL << 63;
  std::cout << "int: " << typename largest_type<int>::type(u) << "\n";
  std::cout << "int, double: " << typename largest_type<int, double>::type(u) << "\n";
  std::cout << "short, float, long long: " << typename largest_type<short, float, long long>::type(u) << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

See it [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/16ee907b8e8684f2a6715b5cb5fc7acc).